# How to delete parent key by its value in firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm a newbie in using firebase real time database and I can't delete products key child with id specified.

[image]

I've tried this approach but it didn't yield any success:

```
removeProductById = async (id, user) => {
    const userProductRef = db.ref(`products/product`);
    try{
        var query = userProductRef.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id);
        query.remove()             
        })

    }catch(error){
        console.log(`The error has occured ${error.message}`)
    }
}
```

So I wanna know how can one delete any tipe of key by whatever value they specify. Thank you in advance, you have always helped me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. Your query doesn't match the nodes you want delete.
2. Firebase doesn't support delete-queries.

#### Your query doesn't match the nodes you want delete

Your query starts at a node `products/product`, which doesn't exist in your database, and then orders/filters the `id` property of each child node.

What you want instead is to start at the `products` node, and then order/filter on its `product/id` property of each child node:

In code:

```
const userProductRef = db.ref(`products`);
var query = userProductRef.orderByChild('product/id').equalTo(id);
```

Don't forget that you'll need to define an index for `product/id` for this on the `products` level in your rules.

#### Firebase doesn't support delete-queries

You can't simply pass the query and delete instruction to Firebase. To write a node in the database, you'll need to know the entire path to that node.

So you'll need to:

1. Execute the a query.
2. Loop over the results in your application code.
3. Delete each matching node individually or in a multi-path update.

With the `query` above, that'd be:

```
query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    child.ref.remove();
  });
})
```

Or with a multi-path/batch update:

```
query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  let updates = {};
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    updates[child.key] = null;
  });
  ref.update(updates);
})
```